# Assign contents of Excel cell to string variable in AutoIT

Tags: excel, autoit

I am writing a script that I want to pull cell values from an Excel spreadsheet containing usernames and passwords.  I wish to use two variables USERNAME and PASSWORD.  I would like to use the data on each row and move down a row with each pass of the loop.

I have looked over Excel UDF included in AutoIT and ExcelCOM_UDF written by a third party.  I cannot seem to find the answers I am looking for.  This should be a very basic function of either of these, but I am having trouble.

I am not looking for a handout, so just a nice reference page is fine. BUT if you have a snippet of what I need, it will not hurt my feelings as I am not determined to write this code solely on my own.

My "A" column will contain the USERNAME variables, and the "B" column will contain my PASSWORD variables.

Added snippet of some code of what I have so far. I have not tried to pull anything from Excel yet, because I cannot find a command that seems to do what I am looking to do. Hopefully seeing the code will give a better picture of my goal.

I DO NOT WISH TO MODIFY THE SPREADSHEET PROGRAMMATICALLY, ONLY SET STRING VARIABLES FROM CELL TEXT.

```
...
    $USERNAME = "usernameHere"  ;I want to set this variable as the text from A1 of c:\test.xls
    $PASSWORD =  "passwordHere" ;I want to set this variable as the text from B1 of c:\test.xls

         ;Username Box
        MouseClick("left",1179,488,1)

        ;Type username
        Send($USERNAME)

        ;Password Box
        MouseClick("left",1179,578,1)

        ;Type Password
        Send($PASSWORD)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to read a spreadsheet containing a list of usernames and password. This function create an array with two dimensions. The first column contains usernames, the second the password. With this

```vb
#include <Array.au3>
#include <Excel.au3>

Func get_data_Excel($filePathExcel)

   Local $error
   Local $oExcel = _ExcelBookOpen($filePathExcel, 0)
   $oExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   $oExcel.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   $error = Int(@error)
   Select
      Case $error = 1
         msgbox(16, "Erreur : Fermeture de l'application", "Code erreur _ExcelBookOpen : 1"&@CRLF&@CRLF&"Impossible de creer l'objet $oExcel avec _ExcelBookOpen")
      Case $error = 2
         msgbox(16, "Erreur : Fermeture de l'application", "Code erreur _ExcelBookOpen : 2"&@CRLF&@CRLF&"Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier "&$filePathExcel&" avec _ExcelBookOpen")
   EndSelect
   If $error > 0 Then
      _ExcelBookClose($oExcel, 0) ; Close without save
      Exit
   EndIf       

   ; Read column A (login) and column B (pwd)
   _ExcelSheetActivate($oExcel, "sheet1")
   $nb_columns = $oExcel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count   
   $nb_rows = $oExcel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
   Local $array_data_excel[$nb_rows][2]
   Local $idx
   For $idx = 0 To $nb_rows-1
      $array_data_excel[$idx][0] = $oExcel.Activesheet.Cells($idx+1, 1).Value
      $array_data_excel[$idx][1] = $oExcel.Activesheet.Cells($idx+1, 2).Value
   Next   

   _ExcelBookClose($oExcel, 0)
   _ArrayDisplay($array_data_excel, "Data from excel file")         
EndFunc
```

And to use this function :

```vb
get_data_Excel("d:\users.xlsx")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <Excel.au3>

Local $MyUsernameArray[5] = [ "Hans", "Gerd", "Walter", "Klaus", "Peter" ] ;Your Username Array
Local $MyPasswordArray[5] = [ "12345", "I", "am", "so", "creative" ] ;Your Password Array

 $oExcel =  _ExcelBookNew(1) ;Set this to 0 if you want it to work in background
_ExcelWriteCell ( $oExcel, "Usernames", "A1" ) ;self explaining (i hope)
_ExcelWriteArray ( $oExcel, 2, 1, $MyUsernameArray ,1) ;^
_ExcelWriteCell ( $oExcel, "Passwords", "B1" );^
_ExcelWriteArray ( $oExcel, 2, 2, $MyPasswordArray ,1);^

_ExcelBookSaveAs($oExcel, @ScriptDir & "\PleaseAtleastPostSomeCodeNextTimeSoWeSeeYouTried", "xls") ;save the file
_ExcelBookClose($oExcel, 1, 0) ;exit and save
```

Comment: Trojan, first let me thank you for your help.  Secondly, I think you misunderstood the question.  I am not looking to add data to the spreadsheet programmatically.  I am looking to have a spreadsheet that will be constantly updated (manually by myself or someone else) that my program will be pulling data FROM.     I will post more details with some code that i am using.

Comment: It is not about being a noob. It is about going in a support forum like this and let just people do the work for you.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get all control with COM/Automation Excel, don't use the UDF , andd deep inside the Com/Automation with the function AutoIt **ObjCreate**. With this function you can get the control of the Object Excel in AutoIt

---

#### COM/Automation with Excel

1) Create reference on COM Object of target application (here this is Excel)

```vb
$oExcel = ObjCreate("Excel.Application")
```

2) Add some options on this instance

```vb
With $oExcel
    .Visible = 1
    .WorkBooks.Add
EndWith
```

3) And now the work can be begin (add some worksheet or data, save the workbook...)

```vb
With $oExcel
    .ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name = "SHEET_ONE"
    .ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1) = "I believe i can fly !!!"
EndWith
```

---

#### Hacks 1 : Save As

```vb
; Create new file with one sheet named "SHEET_ONE"
Local $oExcel = ObjCreate("Excel.Application")
With $oExcel
    .SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
    .Visible = 1
    .WorkBooks.Add
    .ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name = "SHEET_ONE"
    .ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1) = "I believe i can fly !!!"
EndWith

Local $filename = @WorkingDir&"\saveas_excel.xls" 
$oExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = 0
$oExcel.Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
$oExcel.ActiveWorkBook.SaveAs($filename, 1, Default, Default, Default, Default, 2, 1)
$oExcel.Quit
```

---

More information (in french) on http://www.autoitscript.fr/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3272&f=11

Comment: I still think you answered the question backwards.  I do not wish to change any data on the spreadsheet/workbook.  I am writing an application that will use a spreadsheet containing a list of usernames and passwords to log into a portal and then complete some other desired functions.  It will use the spreadsheet AS A SOURCE ONLY to log in to the web based portal, then carry out my desired wishes or execute my custom macros.

Comment: I think to word it perfectly or make it efficient and easy, i need to copy the contents of a specified cell on a spreadsheet to the clipboard.  That is it.  Copy a cell to the clipboard.  I would prefer to set it as a string variable in my script, but putting it on the clipboard will also work.

Comment: Do not post two answers. Put all of them together in one answer and just put a title for each answer so users can easily scan through them and find what's best for thme.